# SMS Sending functionality in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sms

I am working on a project in Rails 4.I have implemented an email functionality in an project via Action Mailer , same I need to do this with message.

I need to send message to every employee on his mobile no,when I click on send button.So how its possible,is there an free API Or gems which I may use. I have seen https://www.twilio.com/ for this,but its paid. I found mailerboxer gems but dont know will it be able to send message or not

Comment: Mail and SMS are two different things. So gems for mails, most probably wont have support for sms And to send sms, you need service of a third party providers like **twilio**.

Comment: What about mailerboxer gem and sms-easy gems in Rails.......how may i use it????????

Comment: mailboxer works like a internal messaging system, like chat. sms-easy depends on carrier(never used it), and that too only some carriers are supported from USA, Japan etc. If you are going to send sms to those country then you can explore that gem, if it works.

Comment: i want it for sending sms in India.Will you suggest me what i may use for it????

Comment: i need to send sms to every employee which i select,but unable to get the required gem which i may use. :/

Comment: Twilio allow send sms free but for that you need to verified that all mobile number which you want to use as testing purpose. Live credential will need paid account.

Comment: I can suggest you to use 'msgwow.com'. They charge 7p/sms. I am not in anyway promoting them, I use their service. Or you can find any other provider.

Comment: do you know any such gem which me help me to achieve this functionality?? i'm not get it on google.....................

Comment: You need an third party provider like the one I mentioned above. Then if they have gem then use it or try to use their API manually. For the provider I mentioned, I have created a [gem](https://github.com/sajan45/msgwow) for my own use. You can use that if you want.

Comment: but is it paid??????

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned you have to pay 7p/sms. I don't think you will find any good service for free.

Comment: how you created the gem?

Answer (score -1):

As a free alternative, You can use [SMSGateway](http://smsgateway.me/), you have to download their app in your android device, and then you can send schedule messages using their API, here's a ruby [GEM](https://github.com/ashhadsheikh/smsgateway) for this API to schedule SMS using just two lines of code.